# c# How to press and hold the key without releasing the key in postmessage?

Tags: c#, keypress, postmessage

How to press and hold the key without releasing the key in postmessage?

I searched and tried various methods, but when I press the key, it comes off immediately.

The code I used is below.

I want to know how to keep pressing

```
private const int VK_KEY_W = 0x57;
    private void sendKey()
    {
        IntPtr Hwnd = FindWindow("LDPlayerMainFrame", "winTitle");
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowEx(Hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "RenderWindow", "TheRender");

        if (!hWnd.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            PostMessage(hWnd, 0x100, VK_KEY_W, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            PostMessage(hWnd, 0x101, VK_KEY_W, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) and friends.

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5264831/How-to-Send-Inputs-using-Csharp

Comment: thanks for the reply
but i want to hold the key press on the program in the background